# how to add extention textalign and text color to tiptap-vuetify in nuxt js?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs, tiptap

how to add extention Text-align and text-color to Tiptap-vuetify in Nuxtjs?

```
     <template #toolbar="{ buttons, commands, isActive }">
        <!--You can render the buttons as you wish (you can see in the source code how this is done).-->
         <button @click="commands.alignment({ align: 'left' })">
           LEFT
          </button>
      </template>
```

Comment: nobody answer for problem?